# Android app icon not showing in running apps

Tags: android, image, icons, assets

Sometimes my app icons are not showing in the list of running apps. It only shows the standard app icon from Android.

I created an image asset from the image I would like to use as the app icon, calling it `ic_launcher` and setting it as `android:icon` in my `AndroidManifest`.

On the left side of the EditorArea (where the line numbers are) you get a little preview image of the used image. It still shows the standard Android icon. But when I click on the image name and open it, it shows my desired app icon, the one I want in my app!

Anywhere else it shows my desired icon perfectly (e.g. in the ActionBar), but not in the list of running apps, nor during the installation from an APK.

Here is my Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="smartweed.unboringbeta" >

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".FullscreenActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".ShowEventMain"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_show_event_main" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".ShowEventDetails"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_show_event_details" >
    </activity>
</application>
```

Here you can see the Image preview showing a wrong image:
[image]

The weird thing is, that this is not happening in all of my projects. I bet if I created a new project it would work just right.

I already tried cleaning, rebuilding and making the project.

Answer (score 2):

use    `android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"` in Activity Tag

```
<activity
        android:name=".FullscreenActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: Tried it and it didnt work. It should work with only adding the icon under the application tag. The problem ist that Android Studio seems to use the wrong picture. As i described the little Image previe inside the edito also shows the wrong picture, even if i add it under the activity tag

Answer (score 0):

You have to add

```
android:logo="@drawable/ic_launcher"
```

or

```
android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
```

under activity tag in Manifest file.

Try like this.

```
<activity
     android:name=".FullscreenActivity"
     android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
     android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
     android:label="@string/app_name"
     android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme" >
     <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
         <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
     </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

**EDIT:**

make sure `mipmap` folder contain your application launcher icon instead of default laucher icon OR try

```
android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
```

instead of

```
android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
```

Comment: Tried it and it didnt work. It should work with only adding the icon under the application tag. The problem ist that Android Studio seems to use the wrong picture. As i described the little Image previe inside the edito also shows the wrong picture, even if i add it under the activity tag

Comment: did you try android:logo and android:icon both?

Comment: yep did that too. It seems to always referecing to the standard picture, maybe it is using the wrong mipmap-Folder? Whenn i wanna create a new Image Asset it always puts me in "C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\plugins\android\lib\templates\gradle-projects\NewAndroidModule\root\res\mipmap-xhdpi\ic_launcher.png" which is the wrong picture....

Comment: i think it's because of android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme" theme you have used in you activity

Comment: Also didnt work, still showing the standard icon in the Image preview in Android Studio

Answer (score 0):

Try this it may help:

Open your AndroidManifest.xml->Select Application tab at the bottom ->In Application Attributes select Icon Browse.. option ->Select Create New icon.. option ->Select Launcher Icons radio button and Next->Select Foreground: Image option and Browse.. your Image File -> choose your image and click Finish->And Select Yes to All in the dialog box,

Comment: I cant find this Application tab when opening my Manifest. Do you mean like the "Design" and "Text" tabs in the xml files?